# The entire code does not fit on the slide. R markdown, Xaringan

Tags: r, xaringan

I am using xaringan in r, when the code is executed it does not appear integer on the slide, it does not fit on the slide, what can I do to make it appear integer?

````
```{r, out.width=1200, out.height=300, out.width=1200, eval=FALSE}
beta_matrix[1:20, 1:6] %>% print(digits = 8)
```
````

Comment: Someone else asked a similar question in the xaringan repo and I'd like to share my reply here in case you are interested: https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/issues/365#issuecomment-1500680476

Answer (score 1):

In your slides you can change the size of the code (and output) with CSS.  Put this in your slides

````
```{css echo=FALSE}
.small-code .remark-code{
  font-size: 45%
}
```
````

Then, you can use that to change the size of code in your slides in the following way.

````
.small-code[
  ```{r, out.width=1200, out.height=300, out.width=1200, eval=FALSE}
  beta_matrix[1:20, 1:6] %>% print(digits = 8)
  ```
]
````

You may have to change the size in the css from `45%` to something else to suit your needs.